# react higher order component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im looking into higher order functions and i dont really understand how this part works.

say i have the following function:

```
const withAdminWarning = WrappedComponent => {
  return props => (
    <div>
      {props.isAdmin && <p>This is private info. Please dont share!</p>}
      <WrappedComponent {...props} />
    </div>
  );
};


const Info = props => (
  <div>
    <h1>Info</h1>
    <p>This info is: {props.info}</p>
  </div>
);

const AdminInfo = withAdminWarning(Info);

ReactDOM.render(
  <AdminInfo isAdmin={true} info="There are the details" />,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

From my understanding of components, to access the props variable, you have to use either props, if its a stateless component, or this.props if it is a class component.

From where does the props come into play in the example above as i cant get access to it from the WrappedComponent or anywhere else apart from the return statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Higher order Component returns a function which is a functional component. Am I right in thinking that `foo(Info)` means `withAdminWarning(Info)`?

So after calling `withAdminInfo` the `AdminInfo` Component looks basically like:

```js
const AdminInfo = props => (
    <div>
        {props.isAdmin && <p>This is private info. Please dont share!</p>}
        <div>
            <h1>Info</h1>
            <p>This info is: {props.info}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```